# JupyterLab - How to add Command(⌘) + Enter for running a cell in macOS ? (How is ⌘ called?)

Tags: macos, jupyter-lab

In MacOS, the default shortcuts for running a Notebook are `Shift + Enter` or `CTRL + Enter`,
But I would like to use `Command (⌘) + Enter` to run a cell.

In Settings I see the list of commands, but how is ⌘ called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (⌘) is called `Accel`, not sure if it is a JupyterLab specific or a general usage of the word.
In anycase, adding the following under Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> User Preferences, allows me to run cells with `⌘ + enter`:

```json
{"shortcuts": 
    [
        {
            "command": "notebook:run-cell",
            "keys": [
                "Accel Enter"
            ],
             "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode"
        },
        {
            "command": "runmenu:run",
            "keys": [
                "Accel Enter"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        },
    ]
}
```